# Excel data validation missing after re-opening file

Tags: vsto, excel-2010

I am adding some data validation on the fly using the following:

```
var cell = sheet.Range["A2", "A1048576"];
cell.Validation.Add(
    XlDVType.xlValidateList,
    XlDVAlertStyle.xlValidAlertStop,
    XlFormatConditionOperator.xlBetween,
    "ABC,DEF,123");
```

This works grand and you will see the ABC,DEF and 123 in the datavalidation dropdown for the column. The issue is after re-opening the sheet later the data validation is gone.  An error is shown [image] 
Click yes then you are presented with: [image]
Click close and your sheet is displayed with all the data already entered but the data validation is gone entirely.

How do I add the validation so it persists and survives save and re-open?

Comment: Does it open without an error if you change your code to:
   var cell = sheet.Range["A2", "A10000"];

Comment: 2nd question is if this is your actual value list or if it's much longer that that?

Comment: @Eddy I set it to A1000 and the error remains. They are  [service,implimentation], [software,system], [consumer,provider], [File,File-Location,One-Way,Service] where square brackets are cols and the lists within are the data validation.

Comment: The code is in the post. var cell .... 123");

Answer (score 1):

This happens if the string exceeds 255 chars (in the above example "ABC,DEF,123"). The better solution (if appliable) is to create the list using a reference and not a collection of strings.